# How to show image in jupyter through vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am using the vscode jupyter extension to edit ipynb file. However, the image that can be successfully shown in jupyter through browser can not be shown through vscode. I have put the image in the same folder as the .ipynb  file.How can I fix the problem? ! My command is like this:

```
![title](fig1.png)
```

Comment: Drag and drop the picture from the folder should still work as I explained it here:  [can not render images in ipynb files on vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73559026/5127304)

Comment: They have already announced that this issue which is referred as  [Jupyter notebook image pasting](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_71#_jupyter) has been included in their [August 2022 release of Visual Studio Code (version 1.71)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_71)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was earlier an issue. It has since been fixed - should work, now. Try it out again.