# can not render images in ipynb files on vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, markdown

i have installed vscode with official microsoft python package , every thing is ok except images rendering in markdown

i tried the following codes for displaying images in markdown cell :

`<img src="images/grad_summary.png" style="width:600px;height:300px;">`

alt

`![title](images/grad_summary.png)`

but it is not working although it is working on jupyter notebook

P.S.

vscode version:  1.40.1

python version : 3.7

vscode python extension version : 2019.10.44104

os : windows 10

Any Help :)

Comment: Although I explained before a simple solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73559026/5127304), they have anounced by 1st of September 2022 that this issue is incluided in their [August 2022 release of Visual Studio Code (version 1.71)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_71) which is mentioned as [Jupyter notebook image pasting](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_71#_jupyter)

Comment: See also [VSCode 1.78 (Apr. 2023)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76062235/6309) new drag and drop feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

seems they have fixed it

```
#%%[markdown]
# ![title](sample_image.png)
```

Comment: `![Inlet Spike](inlet_spike.png)`
Worked for me in VS Code, as an example to others. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.display import Image
Image('image_path')
```

Comment: It's not clear how this answer the question, can you explain how this solution works?

Comment: I use %matplotlib inline and the images/plot/graphs show up correctly, Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027980/purpose-of-matplotlib-inline for more definition

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with local paths to images:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7704

Unfortunately there is no workaround.

Answer (score 1):

First you can drag a picture from VS Code file explorer and then dropping it in a Markdown cell holding `shift` button.

If you still having problems displaying the image, try to delete everything written in the file link except the picture's name. In your case you would have something like this:

`![title](grad_summary.png)`

Comment: This solution worked for me. I was able to drag it from my desktop instead of having to navigate to the image via VSC's file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

As of 31/05/2022,
If you initially create the file in Jupyter Notebook and later open it in VC Code, the code for embedding the picture is:

```
![picTitle](attachment:ch01_05.jpg)
```

Just delete 'attachment:' (to express the reference in the right format)

```
 ![picTitle](ch01_05.jpg)
```

and the picture will load. (given the reference/path to it is still valid)

Comment: But how do you attach inside of vscode

Answer (score 0):

`<img src="images/grad_summary.png">` works for me now

vscode info

```
Version: 1.74.3 (user setup)
Commit: 97dec172d3256f8ca4bfb2143f3f76b503ca0534
Date: 2023-01-09T16:59:02.252Z
Electron: 19.1.8
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
Sandboxed: No
Jupyter extension: v2022.11.1003412109
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ![Tux, the Linux mascot](./assets/images/tux.png)
```

```
 # ![title](./assets/images/tux.png)
```

Work with me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).